# Can't make Azure Conditional Access working

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

**What I am testing**

In order to force MFA, I created a very simple Azure conditional access policy:

- User and group: all users
- Grant: requires MFA

**What I get**

But this rule never applied.

**What I did**

I tester from *WhatIf* tool and from running *Connect-AzAccount* either.

When testing I discovered that if I apply:

- Cloud apps or action: Office 365 (or whatever)

This time *whatIf* is triggered.

**My question**

Could anybody explain me this behavior? What I should do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after watching your question, I started testing  MFA in my tenant. I followed [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-azure-mfa) and it worked finally, and hope it would help you.

I created a test tenant for this scenario, and in azure ad, I need to disable Security default first, [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults) show the operation.

And according to your description, it seems that your configuration didn't work, I assume that you may miss some steps. When adding Conditional Access policy, you need to add policy name, then choose affect scope(users and groups), select Cloud apps or actions(e.g.  choose **Microsoft Azure Management** so the policy applies to sign-in events to the Azure portal), and you need to check the box for **Require multi-factor authentication** under  Access controls->Grant.

Here's my configuration. And when I signed in azure portal with test user, it asked me to use phone to prove myself.

[image][image]

Comment: Yes this is what I discovered. But I don't undersatnd why we absolutely need to set a cloud app or action.
Say Azure works like this

Thanks

Comment: @FrédéricDeLèneMirouze It's great to be able to help you !